# sfdx force:source:push fails with "TypeError: version.match is not a function"

Tags: salesforcedx, push

I am getting the following error after attempting to run the following command to push some code to a new scratch org:

`sfdx force:source:push -u tb-prototype --dev-debug`

Error message:

```
  ERROR running force:source:push:  version.match is not a function 
*** Internal Diagnostic ***

TypeError: version.match is not a function
    at MdapiPackage.setVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/source/mdapiPackage.js:111:25)
    at new MdapiPackage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/source/mdapiPackage.js:103:14)
    at generateMetadataManifestJson (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/source/manifestCreateApi.js:39:23)
    at manifestCreate.createManifest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/source/manifestCreateApi.js:166:33)
    at Function.createPackageManifests (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/source/sourceConvertApi.js:220:14)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/source/sourceConvertApi.js:119:37
    at async MdapiPushApi.doDeploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/source/sourcePushApi.js:47:32)
From previous event:
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
From previous event:
    at SourceApiCommand.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/source/sourceApiCommand.js:52:14)
    at SourcePushCommand.execLegacyCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/ToolbeltCommand.js:148:43)
    at async SourcePushCommand.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/commands/force/source/push.js:25:16)
    at async SourcePushCommand._run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/@salesforce/command/lib/sfdxCommand.js:91:40)
    at async Config.runCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/config.js:172:9)
    at async Main.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/main.js:22:9)
    at async Main._run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/command.js:43:20)
    at async Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/dist/cli.js:32:20)
Outer stack:
    at Function.wrap (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/@salesforce/core/lib/sfdxError.js:151:27)
    at SourcePushCommand.catch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/ToolbeltCommand.js:246:46)
    at async SourcePushCommand._run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/@salesforce/command/lib/sfdxCommand.js:95:13)
    at async Config.runCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/config.js:172:9)
    at async Main.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/main.js:22:9)
    at async Main._run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/command.js:43:20)
    at async Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/dist/cli.js:32:20)
******
```

I have updated to the latest version of `sfdx` to no useful effect...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your apiVersion for the project and sfdx-project.json? Also please mention your OS version and sfdx version and npm version?

Comment: Hello Mohith, thanks for the reply.

In the end I created a brand new fresh scratch org and started again... and that fixed it. So no idea what the underlying problem was...


API version is 48.0 and sfdx cli is 7.63.0 under linux. npm version 6.14.5. 

sfdx-project.json was basically just the stock/plain one that you get with a fresh project :-)

A strange issue.